# How to get the last count, or the last time in a day

Tags: c#

I have a problem finding the last time in the day (the time it's the biggest) picture below, how can I get that time?
I have to compare this time with his shift, but when I do it, I always read for the first time.

This is my code:

```
 foreach (var shift in shifts)
        {  
            if (von.ZPZ_Von <= shift.Arbeitsbeginn.AddMinutes(-20) &&
                bis.ZPZ_Bis >= shift.Arbetsende.AddMinutes(-10))
                return null;

            else if (von.ZPZ_Von >= shift.Arbeitsbeginn.AddMinutes(20) &&
                 bis.ZPZ_Bis >= shift.Arbetsende.AddMinutes(10))
                return null;

            else if (von.ZPZ_Von <= shift.Arbeitsbeginn.AddMinutes(5)
               && bis.ZPZ_Bis <= shift.Arbetsende.AddMinutes(10)
               )
                return shift;

        }
```

It is a method that finds the shift of workers, and if in the correct shift the worker returns the shift, if the worker comes 20 minutes or works more than 10 minutes then returns null.

This looks like data for one day:

So I need to compare the ZPZ_Bis with the last, or rather, the time.
At the moment, my method always compares ZPZ_Bis with the first departure time, i. 1899-12-30 09:52:00.000 in this case.

I would be grateful if somebody could help me with this problem, I have not really known how to handle this in the last few days.

this is my whole method:

```
 private A_Arbeitszeitplan DetectShift(List<A_Arbeitszeitplan> shifts, PRAESENZZEIT von, PRAESENZZEIT bis, List<PRAESENZZEIT>arrivals)
```

Comment: I am utterly and completely confused. Could you give a little intro to your problem that explain what exactly you are trying to do? Then go into the details. I totally cannot follow through why you are doing what you are doing. And another tip: better use english, so non-German speakers can understand the semantics of your vars by their names, too.

Comment: I apologize for this, ZPZ_Bis = Time to, ZPZ_Von = time of, Time ZPZ_Bis I need to find which is the last in the day, can I then compare it with a shift that is appropriate to it.

Comment: I agree. It would be good in general if you could provide some more information, especially about the type of your objects. This will make it easier to understand your problem.

Comment: _" if the worker comes 20 minutes or works more than 10 minutes then returns null."_ I totally miss the reasoning behind this part.

Comment: Based on this condition: `bis.ZPZ_Bis >= shift.Arbetsende.AddMinutes(-10)`, you'll be returning `null` for any worker who finishes 10 minutes *early* or more. Also, you've spelled *'Arbetsende'* incorrectly for this method.

Comment: @Fildor I apologize if a worker came 20 minutes before his shift, or if his time is up to 10 minutes at work, then returns null

Comment: Also, if this is SQL data, you could analyse it with SQL before you send the results.  Perhaps you could simplify this for us all, by explaining the meaning of your variables and methods in the post itself.  Just click the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52110558/edit).

Comment: OK, but why does it return null? I get there are shifts ... let's say you have like from 7am-1pm and 1pm-8pm (just random numbers). And you have workers that come and go ( actually stamp in and out ). That gives you a list of "come-and-go" times. Now you do what and expect what?

Comment: @Fildor I return a zero for workers who do not come to their working hours assigned to them in shifts, the idea of a vault is that workers who have not come to their shift to be shown with a certain string

Comment: Ahhh ok. So you actually need to know if they are "present" for their assigned shift. Do you have a marker for breaks? So you can determine if they are actually "not there" or just "using the restroom" ?

Comment: And also important: Shifts cannot cross date-boundary? Like a nightshift from 9pm -4am ?

Comment: @Fildor I added a list of arrivals, I can get the time from(ZPZ_VON) and time to(ZPZ_Bis). Can I use the linq to get out of ZPZ_bis lasttime?

Comment: @Fildor The pause has already been canceled

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to use the `TimeSpan` of your `DateTime` you can get it like so:

> From a DateTime, you can use .TimeOfDay - but that gives you a
>   TimeSpan representing the time into the day (10 hours).

Of course you need to compare TimeSpans with eachother:

```
if (von.ZPZ_Von.TimeOfDay <= shift.Arbeitsbeginn.AddMinutes(-20).TimeOfDay &&
            bis.ZPZ_Bis.TimeOfDay >= shift.Arbetsende.AddMinutes(-10).TimeOfDay)
            return null;
```